# What is a good wireless solution for video monitoring for BlackMagic Design Cinema Cameras?

Tags: video, monitoring, wireless

We are looking for a video monitoring solution that is portable and used with the BlackMagic Design Camera. I found a link with devices that look great.

http://blog.vincentlaforet.com/mygear/monitoring-viewing/

Was wondering if any of you have experience with any of these devices. And if you have any other recommendations.

Thank you for all your help.